# Warning: atop.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units

Tags: centos7, monitoring, systemd, daemon, atop

I was trying to change the atop log interval on **CentOS 7 cPanel server** from *600* to *60* seconds and tried editing the file `/etc/system/system/multi-user.target.wants/atop.service` (Environment="LOGINTERVAL=60") and did `service atop restart`, then edited `/usr/share/atop/atop.daily`(LOGINTERVAL=60) and did `service atop restart` but couldn't see that bringing intended result.

So, I tried editing `/usr/lib/systemd/system/atop.service` (Environment="LOGINTERVAL=60") which I saw in `service atop status`

After this when I checked `service atop status` I'm seeing a warning `Warning: atop.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.`

```
[root@**** ~]# service atop status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status atop.service
● atop.service - Atop advanced performance monitor
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/atop.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since *** ****-**-** **:**:** GMT; 29min ago
     Docs: man:atop(1)
  Process: 20856 ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/find ${LOGPATH} -name atop_* -mtime +${LOGGENERATIONS} -exec rm -v {} ; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20852 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c test -n "$LOGGENERATIONS" -a "$LOGGENERATIONS" -eq "$LOGGENERATIONS" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20851 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c test -n "$LOGINTERVAL" -a "$LOGINTERVAL" -eq "$LOGINTERVAL" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20855 (atop)
   CGroup: /system.slice/atop.service
           └─20855 /usr/bin/atop -w /var/log/atop/atop_******** 600

*
*
*
Warning: atop.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.


[root@**** ~]# service atop restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart atop.service
Warning: atop.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.


[root@**** ~]# service atop status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status atop.service
● atop.service - Atop advanced performance monitor
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/atop.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since *** ****-**-** **:**:** GMT; 5s ago
     Docs: man:atop(1)
  Process: 25789 ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/find ${LOGPATH} -name atop_* -mtime +${LOGGENERATIONS} -exec rm -v {} ; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25785 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c test -n "$LOGGENERATIONS" -a "$LOGGENERATIONS" -eq "$LOGGENERATIONS" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25784 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c test -n "$LOGINTERVAL" -a "$LOGINTERVAL" -eq "$LOGINTERVAL" (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 25788 (atop)
   CGroup: /system.slice/atop.service
           └─25788 /usr/bin/atop -w /var/log/atop/atop_******* 600

*
*
*
Warning: atop.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

How should I proceed at this point? I didn't try running `systemctl daemon-reload` as I'm not sure what all changes it'll bring

Comment: It will reread the configuration files including your changes. Read the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [systemctl(1)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#daemon-reload),

> `daemon-reload`
>
> Reload the systemd manager configuration. This will rerun all
> generators (see [systemd.generator(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html#)), reload all unit files, and
> recreate the entire dependency tree. While the daemon is being
> reloaded, all sockets systemd listens on behalf of user configuration
> will stay accessible.

However, you should not edit the units under `/usr/lib/systemd/` as they are controlled by the RedHat Package Manager (RPM) and will be replaced by updates. See the correct paths from [systemd.unit(5) Unit File Load Path](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20File%20Load%20Path).

| Path | Description |
| --- | --- |
| /etc/systemd/system | System units created by the administrator |
| /usr/local/lib/systemd/system | System units installed by the administrator |
| /usr/lib/systemd/system | System units installed by the distribution package manager |

You could place your setting as a *dropin* in `/etc/systemd/system/atop.service.d/interval.conf`:

```
[Service]
Environment=LOGINTERVAL=60
```

After that, yes, you need to run the `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.